# Critical section in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, critical-section

Is it possible to enter critical section in perl, to hold other threads and do some calculations in single thread? Like in .NET:

```
lock(_syncRoot)
{
   // Single-threaded zone
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Perl has locks and semaphores.  See [the documentation on threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Synchronization-and-control) for details and examples.

Perl version of your code:

```
{
    lock($_syncRoot);
    # Single-threaded zone
}
```

Comment: Just for interest, so I can put lock on database handler in that way?

Comment: You can call the lock function on any variable.  That variable could be your DB handle, or it could just be a `$db_lock` var that you use to track when the DB handler is locked.  Either way, you're just creating a critical section within the scope of the lock().

Comment: They're "handles" (gives you a hold on), not handlers (takes an action in response to)

Comment: @ikegami Hmm..you're explaining me difference with handler and thread-locking? I can't understand what you meant.

Comment: No, I'm correcting your English. I'm saying the term is "database handle", not "database handler".